# Omniauth/MYSQL awkwardness in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am using 'omniauth' and 'omniauth-facebook' gem for Rails 3.2, with Ruby 2.0, Today I've encountered an awkward situation that I couldn't find any solution for. Every user was using the facebook login perfectly until this.

My Routes

```
# Facebook authentication
match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
```

My session controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController


 def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.uid
    redirect_to user
  end

....
```

My session model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.id = auth.uid
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    if !user.username
        user.username = auth.uid
    end
    user.username = auth.info.nickname
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender
    user.is_admin = false
    user.picture = "http://graph.facebook.com/#{auth.uid}/picture?type=large&height=324&width=580"
    user.updated_at = auth.extra.raw_info.updated_time
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
end
end
```

Let me show you the awkward part. A user is authenticated, lets call it TESTUSER, but instead of his current id, Rails redirects and sets the Session id different from its original ID.

```
 User Load (132.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`provider` = 'facebook' AND `users`.`uid` = 100006300277396 LIMIT 1
   (129.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (130.6ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`age`, `bio`, `created_at`, `email`, `experience`, `fat_percentage`, `gender`, `height`, `id`, `is_admin`, `location`, `mass`, `name`, `oauth_expires_at`, `oauth_token`, `password`, `picture`, `provider`, `salt`, `uid`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2013-07-09 15:32:14', 'TESTUSER@yandex.com', NULL, NULL, 'male', NULL, 100006300277396, 0, NULL, NULL, 'Test User', '2013-09-07 06:49:53', 'CAAHrxXWCZBwsBAEtkOVHkTHC5bMPlr6Q9IbWRSCBLzfEZBmSwKZAtr9ebHCxjO4xStcg9tew90u9fhVl2cTcIx7za6nJYz4wuMQmx7UrQDQntT1nGVOFy87ctuDAHS1jQueV0KXC3MvkWGZCn9ccprzJ8w4pKP0ZD', NULL, 'http://graph.facebook.com/100006300277396/picture?type=large&height=324&width=580', 'facebook', NULL, 100006300277396, '2013-07-09 10:33:49', 'TESTUSER')

Started GET "/users/100006300277396" for 88.248.139.159 at 2013-07-09 15:32:14 +0000
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"100006300277396"}
  User Load (130.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 100006300277396 LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 170ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=100006300277396):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `show'
```

In the console it says that the user's ID is 100006300277396 but on the database it is set to 2147483647.

I've found out that the MYSQL statement works perfectly well, but because ID was auto-increment before, it inserts the last auto incremented value to the database. Therefore, the problem is with database, do you see any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set INT(11) as BIGINT(11) to fix this situation